# react jest : Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have been trying to implement tests with Jest for the first time and I have encountered the following error. I have also tried the recommended fixes found in other threads and have not fixed my problem.

It seems that my "import" does not work at certain levels of my app.

setupTests.js

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
});
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
  };
```

jest.config.json

```
{
    "setupFiles": [
        "raf/polyfill",
        "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.12",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.14.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "reactour": "^1.18.0",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "victory": "^35.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "testJ": "jest --config=jest.config.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to run my test suite I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/tests/add.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/jk/EpitechProjects/T-WEB-700/CountOfMoney_18/front/src/setupTests.js:6
    import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below to your jest.config.json file:

```
 transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js?)$": "babel-jest"
  },
```

Comment: Please mark this as accepted if it helped you so that others can also benefit from it :)